# javascript - image preview before upload

Tags: javascript

iam trying to show image preview before upload, for that i am using code given below..

it works with firefox, but, dosent work with IE8

```
<%= image_tag @image, :id=>"preview-photo" %>
<%= file_field 'image','photo', :onchange => "preview(this);" %>


function preview(this) {
document.getElementById("preview-photo").src =this.value;
return;
}
```

i need help..
Is there any solution to preview the image in IE8 and other browsers?

Comment: This is no longer possible across browsers for security reasons (they serve `C:\Fakepath` instead of the real value when querying a file upload field). I do not think there is a workaround.

Comment: any other approach to do this functionality...using any plugins???

Comment: Flash based uploaders can theoretically still do this, although I don't know any specific product that does it out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of is using a flash movie for your upload. For a nice example see [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/25/previewing-an-image-before-uploading-it-using-the-filereference-class-in-flash-player-10/).

Comment: Nice link. This is the best way to go I think