# javascript jquery preview image before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Refs:

[How to preview a image before upload using JavaScript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870943/how-to-preview-a-image-before-upload-using-javascript-or-jquery)
[javascript - image preview before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594099/javascript-image-preview-before-upload)
[How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)

didn't worked for me... from above refs some only worked in ff and some is uploading first and then only showing preview.

I find the exact solution in: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

It works in all i have tested.

I find it working but my code isn't working. So what is the keypoint blueimp is following and i missing for enabling image preview before upload.

I tried with :

> ```
>         $('.hidFileBtn').live('change', function(e){
>             $childImg = $(this).closest('.parent').find('img.previewImg');
>             var FileName = $(this).val();
>             console.log(FileName + "-" + $(this)[0].value);
>             $childImg[0].src = $(this).val();
>         });
> ```

But no luck.

Comment: difficult without resorting to flash or applets i guess..

Comment: Have you tried from: http://saravani.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/preview-of-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded/

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your javascript and create a file button attach onchange event like this onchange="preview_image(event)" code from this [Display Image Before Upload](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/preview-image-before-upload-using-javascript.php) tutorial

```
function preview_image(event) 
{
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function()
  {
    var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
    output.src = reader.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the FileReader of HTML5.If you want to support IE,  use this :

```
div.css({'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale,src="' + input.val() + '")'});
```

Answer (score 0):

This link has a good answer: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

```
<input type = "file" name = "fileFind" onchange = "readURL(this)" id = "fileFind" />
<img id = "imagePreview" src = "" alt = "" />

function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#imagePreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function preview_image(event) 
{
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function()
 {
  var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
  output.src = reader.result;
 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
</script>
<style>
body
{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
 font-family:helvetica;
 background-color:#0B3861;
}
#wrapper
{
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
 width:995px;
}
#output_image
{
 max-width:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="preview_image(event)">
 <img id="output_image"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```